# iOS application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController:

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

XMPP
Using to tableview i am trying to go to next view controller with particular username. so for that i have implemented UItablevie's `didselectrowatIndexpath` correctly. but when i click on username it will gives error like this.

> application tried to push a nil view controller on target.
>
> "<"UINavigationController: 0x7fe831dac0d0>.
>   2015-06-04 14:22:51.063

I have declared storyboard in appdelegate.m like this.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
      ChatViewController *ChatViewController1 = [[ChatViewController alloc]init];
self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];


return YES;
}
```

and here is my tableview's Delegate method.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
[self.tblvwbuddy deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = nil;
user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

ChathistryViewController *chathistory1 = [[ChathistryViewController alloc] init]; // or initWith...
chathistory1 = [appdelegate.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChathistryViewController"];//My next view controller's name
     chathistory1.chatUserObject = user;

      chathistory1.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

chathistory1.self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = user.displayName;

[self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:chathistory1 animated:YES];

}
```

What i am missing in this ? or where i am wrong?

Comment: either your `appdelegate.storyboard` or `chathistory1` object is `nil`. If storyboard object is non-nil than ensure you have a scene in storyboard with the same identifier as you mentioned in the code initialisation.

Comment: how can these storyboards become nil randomly ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 UITabBarController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
        NSArray *listViewController=vc.viewControllers;
        vc.selectedViewController=[listViewController objectAtIndex:1];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

ps.... listViewController objectAtIndex: 1 <--- indicates the position that you want to show your viewcontroller

Comment: got error like >: Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fa460c4bb50>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'Main'

Comment: You must not use the name "main" and this is an example.
You must have to set the field name "Storyboard ID" for example "main"
then try to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     ChatViewController *ChatViewController1 = [[ChatViewController alloc]init];
     self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

     //HOW DID YOU DECLARE the rootViewController?
     /*
     you CANNOT do this: 
     self.window.rootViewController = ChatViewController1;
     */

     //you MUST have declared it like: right? becuase your are using navigationController
     UINavigationController *navigationView = self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"naviController"/*Storyboard ID*/];
     self.window.rootViewController = navigationView;

     //Manually setting navigationController rootViewController, example your rootViewController is ChatViewController
     UIViewController = self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChatViewController"/*Storyboard ID*/];
     [navigationView setViewControllers:UIViewController animated:NO];

     return YES;
}
```

**End Edit**

```
chathistory1 = [appdelegate.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChathistryViewController"];troller
```

You have to set Custom class, in your case: (*ChathistryViewController*)

[image]

And make sure your **`ChathistryViewController`** as the **Storyboard ID** exist in your storyboard

from your code:

```
chathistory1 = [appdelegate.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChathistryViewController"];
```

and i think it is much better allocating it like:

```
//From your code [[ChathistryViewController alloc] init]; will be use less
ChathistryViewController *chathistory1 = [[ChathistryViewController alloc] init]; 
chathistory1 = [appdelegate.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChathistryViewController"];
```

Much better allocation:

```
ChathistryViewController *chathistory1 = [appdelegate.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChathistryViewController"];
```

Another is your `[appdelegate.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:];`

where did you declare the `appdelegate` ?

You can access AppDelegates Property by:

```
ChathistryViewController *chathistory1 = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChathistryViewController"];
```

Comment: `UIViewController *navigationView = self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"naviController"/*Storyboard ID*/];` chathistry is not my initial view controller.

Comment: when i write this code storyboard set `chathistry`as my initial viewcontrollar.

Comment: i have set. but still when i open it directly show chathistoryviewcontroller.

Comment: have you unchecked `is initial View Controller` for `chathistoryviewcontroller` ? i'll edit my answer for manually assigning of navigationController rootViewController..

Answer (score 0):

I guess your story board didn't initialised properly because of that you are getting error.

Instead of creating storyboard object in delegate class follow below approach to retrieve story board object.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Let me know if it worked or not.